# Pop-up reminder and todo app?

Tags: software-recommendation

Does anyone know of a reasonably lightweight app for Ubuntu that can sit in the system tray and pop up to remind me of various tasks?

Something like Kalarm is exactly what I am looking for, but on my system I seem to suffer from the bug regarding shutting down (i.e. Kalarm or perhaps nepomuk stalls the shutdown by a few minutes, and I get the report about processes still running etc). Thus, I've had to remove Kalarm and need to find an alternative.

Can anybody recommend something?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Sticky notes](https://github.com/umangv/indicator-stickynotes)!

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:umang/indicator-stickynotes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-stickynotes
```

Hope you find it useful.

PS: You can also have: [Alarm Clock — Ubuntu Apps Directory](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/alarm-clock-applet/)

Look at the third picture in the Store and you will see it will also satisfy your needs I hope.

Comment: Thanks, I've since found the updated version (not the one in the repositories that seems to lack some of functionality I need) of Indicator-Remindor to also be quite good. Just need to remember to select dialog box as well as pop-up or the remindors can often vanish to quickly, or when away from PC...

Comment: Although one annoying feature of Indicator-Reimindor is that if the computer is off when the alert is scheduled, you do not get the alarm on login next time, it just quietly files it away in "past alerts". Annoying.

Comment: can we add reminders from the terminal to this app ? any keyboard shortcuts for this ?

Comment: Not working in Ubuntu 20.04. Say "Unable to locate package indicator-remindor:

Comment: @ArvindKumar This answer is different from [the other one](https://askubuntu.com/a/670086/816190) and no where mentions `indicator-remindor`.

Answer (score 4):

There is also the default calendar in XFCE: **[Orage](https://web.archive.org/web/20180303185803/http://www.kolumbus.fi/%7Ew408237/orage/orage_doc_4_7.html#orage-eventlist-window)**. It can be installed using:

```
sudo apt install orage
```

Once installed, the calendar user-interface is very similar to that found in Microsoft Outlook.

Answer (score 2):

> **Note:** The below mentioned PPA was last updated for 15.10 (Wily Werewolf) and do not have release files for newer releases. Thus, this PPA is unlikely to work on newer systems.

Another way is

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bhdouglass/indicator-remindor
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-remindor
```

working great! See [Add and Receive Reminders On Your Desktop in Ubuntu - maketecheasier](https://www.maketecheasier.com/add-receive-reminders-on-desktop-in-ubuntu/) for more details

Comment: Very sadly, but it doesn't work for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS... https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-remindor/+bug/1591787

Comment: Doesn't work on 16.10 either :-(

Comment: `Unable to locate package indicator-remindor` ~ Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: hangs on `ubuntu 14.04`

Comment: Discontinued from 14.10+

Comment: Not worked on **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS**  `Unable to locate package indicator-remindor`

Comment: Not working in Ubuntu 20.04. Say "Unable to locate package indicator-remindor:

Answer (score 0):

There's also xpad which can be installed using:

```
sudo apt install xpad
```

I find this one more visually appealing, with easier accessible options right on the notepad itself, as well as more customizable options in the preferences menu.