# Software for displaying daily messages

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm looking for an app which allow me to write daily tasks and to schedule them for displaying at certain schedule.

For example:

```
Daily Task

13:00 PM - Lunch
15:00 PM - Workout
20:00 PM - Medicine
21:00 PM - Reading
```

Comment: Nudge -"sudo apt-get install nudge"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pop-up reminder and todo app?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/401807/pop-up-reminder-and-todo-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Alarm Clock](http://alarm-clock.pseudoberries.com/)

> Alarm Clock is a fully-featured alarm clock for your GNOME panel or equivalent. It's easy to use yet powerful with support for multiple repeatable alarms, as well as snoozing and a flexible notification system.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm using this Alarm Clock, and not bad I'm liking. Thanks